# How to do a proper filter on my Conversation model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have those 2 simple models:

```
class Message(BaseModel):
    src = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='message_src')
    dst = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='message_dst')
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,
                               verbose_name=_(u'Messages'))
class Conversation(BaseModel):

    personnes = models.ManyToManyField(Personne, related_name='conversations')
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, related_name='conversations')
```

I'm made `personnes` a `ManyToManyField` (instead of only `src` and `dst`) so I can have as many `Person` as I need for the conversation.

My problem is when I have 2 persons like this:

```
p_src = Personne.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
# i've got id_dst somewhere before
p_dst = Personne.objects.get(pk=id_dst)
```

And I want to retrieve "the Conversation where there are only those two persons".

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
c = Conversation.objects.filter(
    personnes__in=[p_src, p_dst]).distinct()
```

But the results looks like "the Conversation where there are **one of** those two persons".

How should I do?

Comment: Try removing `__in` -> `...filter(personnes=[p_src, p_dst]).distinct()`

Comment: If I try (already done **`:)`** ) I get: `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: I'm thinking about doing the opposite: starting from Person, like "Give me the intersection of all conversations of those two persons"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution, which is not optimized at all, so if you have any other better solution, I'm your man!

```
# filter all conversations where there are 2 participants and
# (1) src is part of them
convs_src = Conversation.objects.annotate(c=Count('personnes'))\
    .filter(c=2)\
    .filter(personnes__in=[p_src])
# (2) dst is part of them
convs_dst = Conversation.objects.annotate(c=Count('personnes'))\
    .filter(c=2)\
    .filter(personnes__in=[p_dst])
# ... then take the intersection, which should always be "one":
convs = set(list(convs_src)).intersection(list(convs_dst))
if len(convs):  # get() = pour avoir un objet (!= QuerySet)
    c = Conversation.objects.get(pk=convs[0])
else:
    raise Exception('should never ever happen')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
c = Conversation.objects.filter(personnes=p_src).filter(personnes=p_dst).distinct()
```

Comment: If I try your solution I have an obvious Python error: "keyword argument repeated"

Comment: And if I try `c = Conversation.objects.filter(personnes=p_src).filter(personnes=p_dst).distinct()` I get `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'personnes'`

Comment: Right. I edited my answer. Try chaining the `filter`

Comment: Sure? The error looks like you've tried to access `...filter(personnes=p_src).personnes`

Comment: Are you sure that `p_src` is a `Personne` model (create an empty model with only foreign key to `user`). Because when it's the case, the message is logical: you can't ask a "group" = personnes to be equal to only one `Person` model

Answer (score 0):

You would need 2 steps to achieve this. First, make sure that the count of `personnes` is equal to however many `Personne` you want to match. Then you filter on that field for each `Personne` instance:

```
from django.db.models import Count

personnes = [p_src, p_dst]
result = Conversation.objects.annotate(c=Count('personnes')).filter(c=len(personnes))
for personne in personnes:
    result = result.filter(personnes=personne)
```

Comment: I dont know, but it doesn't work for sure. I've just used your `count` and `anotate` sample to make my own version working (see my answer). So I upvote you so you dont have negative vote. But did you really try your solution?

Comment: Can you specify what's not working? I don't have the exact model setup you have but I used it before.

Comment: You could just do an empy Personne model with one field: a foreignkey to user

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to find all conversations where p_src and p_dst are in some role.

```
conversations_where_two_are_in = Conversations.objects.all().filter(
    Q(personnes = p_src)|
    Q(personnes = p_dst)
)
```

And throw away all conversations where other personnes are involved in these conversations. I'd find all personnes besides these two we're interested in and put them in a list.

```
list_of_other_personnes = Personnes.objects.all().exclude(
    personnes = p_src,
    personnes = p_dst,
)
```

I'd exclude them from conversations which our two are in.

```
conversations_between_only_two = conversations_where_two_are_in.exclude(
    personnes__in = list_of_other_personnes)
```

I hope it can help you. Let me know it is not, please.

Comment: Hi, you do 3 queries, and my solution does 2. I dont know which one is the fastest. What do you think?